# TYPO3: Backend login redirects to index.php

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, backend

Recently I have been having some problems with my typo3 installation on my webhosting. One of those problems is, that whenever I login to backend I get redirected to index.php and not the backend. The admin panel is shown on the index.php indicating that the it logs in successfully but then why can't I go to the backend interface.

I have tried several things, like clearing the be_sessions table in the database, clearing the browser cookies, deleting the cache, testing on other web browsers etc. but still no luck.

I am using TYPO3 4.6. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: anomalies in your htaccess ?  wrong sym. links ?

Comment: @rob-ot Thanks for your comment. I can't figure out anything wrong with my .htaccess. Here is the content of the file. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(typo3|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|typo3conf|typo3temp|uploads|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico)/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule .* index.php`